# Gremlin query for sorted results starting from result with specified string attribute

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I have some vertices in my graph with String attributes called someAttribute, example 4 vertices with different "someAttribute" values:

```
someAttribute = "aaa"
someAttribute = "bb1" 
someAttribute = "c" 
someAttribute = "d"
```

I sorted it using sort() by "someAttribute" and I need to query for vertices with attribute greater than "c" (so I expect vertices with attribute "d" in results), but it looks like gt predicate expects a number. How can I achieve it with String attribute?

```
traversal.order().by("someAttribute")
                    .has("someAttribute", gt("c"))
                    .range(0, 2);
```

Comment: You should be able to use `gt` on text. Which graph database backend are you using?

Comment: I am using janusgraph. I tried but then my search for vertices returned nothing.

Comment: is it possible that some special characters (/, :, // ) might be a problem?

Comment: I did some tests using TinkerGraph and also using Neptune and the `gt('c')` type syntax worked fine. I'll try JanusGraph also.

Comment: I added an answer showing the tests that worked for me. Which JanusGraph version do you have, and what is the backend store being used?

Comment: janusgraph:
    image: janusgraph/janusgraph:0.5.3
 janusgraph-storage:
    image: cassandra:2.1.22
  janusgraph-index:
    image: elasticsearch:7.9.1

Answer (score 0):

In general, using `gt` etc. on text values should work. I have tested using TinkerGraph, Amazon Neptune, and JanusGraph.

The tests below were conducted using a JanusGraph 0.6 snapshot that I have on my machine (it was made just before 0.6 was GA). I used the `inmemory` graph, with full graph scans enabled.

```java
gremlin> graph=JanusGraphFactory.open('conf/mem.properties')
==>standardjanusgraph[inmemory:[127.0.0.1]]

gremlin> g=graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[standardjanusgraph[inmemory:[127.0.0.1]], standard]

gremlin> g.addV('test').property('text',"abc")
==>v[4168]
gremlin> g.addV('test').property('text',"def")
==>v[4104]
gremlin> g.addV('test').property('text',"hij")
==>v[4112]
gremlin> g.addV('test').property('text',"xyz")
==>v[8264]
gremlin> g.tx().commit()
==>null

gremlin> g.V()
09:23:24 WARN  org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx  - Query requires iterating over all vertices [()]. For better performance, use indexes
==>v[4104]
==>v[4112]
==>v[4168]
==>v[8264]

gremlin> g.V().has('text',gt('d'))
09:23:39 WARN  org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx  - Query requires iterating over all vertices [(text > d)]. For better performance, use indexes
==>v[4104]
==>v[4112]
==>v[8264]

gremlin> g.V().has('text',gt('d')).values('text')
09:23:48 WARN  org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx  - Query requires iterating over all vertices [(text > d)]. For better performance, use indexes
==>def
==>hij
==>xyz
```